# Cannot access file after moving it to documents directory

Tags: ios, swift3, cloudkit, nsdocumentdirectory

I have an App that uses `CloudKit` as backend, which has some `CKRecords` with some `CKAssets`

Some of those assets are `PDF` files, and I'm failing to open them in the `QuickLook Previewer`

After fetching the records, I save the `CKAsset` `URLs` in an array, with the following code:

```
guard let assets = attachment["attachments"] as? [CKAsset] else { return }
assets.forEach({ (asset) in
    attachmentsURLs.append(asset.fileURL)
})
```

Each `fileURL` gets printed somehow like this:

`file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C4406091-B55C-46AC-A612-69052F2275BB/Library/Caches/CloudKit/34af81edf8344be1cf473ef394e06ccc8e1bc8cf/Assets/85DEDDB6-FB5B-4BC9-AB93-D8951AC304F7.012af7f83e322df6d0d1829b94956e4b829edbe974`

The last string : `85DEDDB6-FB5B-4BC9-AB93-D8951AC304F7.012af7f83e322df6d0d1829b94956e4b829edbe974` is the file itself, and having this I try to move this file to `DocumentsDirectory`.

I try to move them and rename them and give them the specific extension, in this particular case will be `.pdf`

I do this with the following code:

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
var url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath)
let component = NSUUID().uuidString + "." + fileExtensions[index]
url.appendPathComponent(component)

do {
    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: fileURL as URL, to: url)
} catch {
    print("Failed to save attachment with extension with error:", error)
    return
}
```

As you can see, I move the cached file to documents directory and rename it with a random string + file extension.

Using the iOS Simulator, everything works as expected.

The file gets moved from here:
`file:///Users/ivancantarino/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CCE2FCA5-05F0-4BB7-9A25-CBC168398A62/data/Containers/Data/Application/561A3461-0048-4676-808F-2D96B74DBDCD/Library/Caches/CloudKit/34af81edf8344be1cf473ef394e06ccc8e1bc8cf/Assets/FADF0479-E7AE-4340-83C5-C9E0889E4E87.012af7f83e322df6d0d1829b94956e4b829edbe974`

to here:

`file:///Users/ivancantarino/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CCE2FCA5-05F0-4BB7-9A25-CBC168398A62/data/Containers/Data/Application/561A3461-0048-4676-808F-2D96B74DBDCD/Documents/52CAC8CD-EF0E-4E55-8D1B-8B267D07BAAA.pdf`

And them I fill the `QuickLook` datasource and I can visualize the files as expected, however in a real iPhone device this doesn't work.

The preview shows an empty file, with `ZERO KB`.

On a real device the file gets moved from here:

`file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6870DDC2-32FD-4FF2-89F4-04F87BBE534B/Library/Caches/CloudKit/34af81edf8344be1cf473ef394e06ccc8e1bc8cf/Assets/A187A987-BE4E-4C6A-9CBE-E66F3FEF7333.012af7f83e322df6d0d1829b94956e4b829edbe974`

to here:

`file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6870DDC2-32FD-4FF2-89F4-04F87BBE534B/Documents/FD501C6D-9E95-46DD-BC58-EA2C45B62DAC.pdf`

What can be causing this issue?

Why does this works in the simulator and doesn't work on the device?

I've tried a lot of different stuff and this is driving me crazy.

Any hint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved the issue and it was a bit embarrassing to be honest, and I'll explain.

Since I'm using `QuickLook` framework from Apple, which is pretty amazing in my opinion, I had to implement the `QuickLook protocol` methods in order to fill the `datasource` to be able to present the desired files, and the problem was right here.

After fetching the desired files I saved the `URLs` in a `[URL]` array.

In the `QuickLook protocol` method `numberOfPreviewItems(:_)` I return the `[URL].count` as the number of items and in the `previewController(:_)->QLPreviewItem` I was doing the following:

```
func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
    let doc = URL(fileURLWithPath: attachmentURLs[index].absoluteString)
    return doc as QLPreviewItem
}
```

But if you notice, the `doc` variable was initiated with a `URL(fileWithPath)` and I was passing the `URL.absoluteString` which doesn't point to the specific file;

Instead I converted that line to the following:

```
let doc = URL(fileURLWithPath: attachmentURLs[index].path)
```

Since I want to access the `Path` of the given cached `URL`, and by doing this everything worked perfectly.

What was an headache was that with the previous implemented way it worked in the `iOS Simulator` but not on the real device, and that lead me to seek the answer in different ways.